# GCM and multi threading

Tags: android, multithreading, google-cloud-messaging

I've been looking for some time now, information about if it's possible to multi thread sending messages to GCM.

We all know that GCM limits sending a message to 1000 devices max (while using Http). So is it possible to create multiple threads to send a message to 1000 devices times an X number of threads to speed up the process ?

My goal is to send out to millions of devices messages as fast as possible, so if there is a better way to do this, please redirect me to whatever information you have.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You might want to try Topic Messaging, its limit is 1M. https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no limit on the number of concurrent requests you make. But as ztan pointed out, you should consider using topics. Or, if topic messaging doesn't work for you, I'd suggest you use CCS (XMPP Connection Server) for better resource utilization. With CCS you can as well open concurrent connections, if you need.

Comment: thank you for this response. I can't use topics and I can't use CCS either because for the latest I need to track who gets messages or not.

Comment: @Fanta1090 you might be confusing something because CCS in no way gives you less information than HTTP interface. Even more, because with CCS you can request delivery receipts to know when message was actually received on end device.